# php select query unknown column in field list?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having an error in mysql query (Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'p.post_id' in 'field list') 
`post_id` is present in the post table 
can any one help me in this issue

```
SELECT u.iname , p.post_id,p.file_path
FROM users u
INNER JOIN likes l
ON u.user_id=l.user_id
INNER JOIN notify n
ON p.post_id=n.post_id
INNER JOIN post p
ON p.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id=3 AND n.notify=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Tables are not joined in the correct order, you cant reference post_id in the second join as the posts table isn't joined yet.

```
SELECT u.iname, p.post_id, p.file_path
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN likes l ON u.user_id = l.user_id
INNER JOIN post p ON u.user_id p.user_id
INNER JOIN notify n ON p.post_id = n.post_id
WHERE u.user_id = 3 AND n.notify = 1
```